# Tmp36 spike and dip

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor

I'm measuring two temperatures  and powering both tmp36 sensors off of the 5v pin.  For some reason pin A0 (t0) will periodically spike or dip 100°f over actual ambient and pin A1 (t1) will spike or dip but only by about 30°f at the same time but not necessarily in the same direction at A0.

I'm using about 4' of 24ga solid wire to each sensor.

This began with a wall adapter putting out 5v 850ma connected to the barrel connector

Previous adapter of 5.3v 2a worked fine connected via USB.

I don't think it's SW because the arduino is doing exactly what I want it to do: measure t0 and t1 and write them to a database table via wifi.  I'm thinking that I need a 5.3v 2a barrel connector.  Am I right?

Comment: You should read the specifications of the Arduino board. It states that you need at least 6V on the barrel jack, preferably 7V minimum.

Comment: Well...there ya' go.  User error.